# Weird behavior of JavaScript with QML

Tags: javascript, qml

weird behavior of java script.
I am trying to develop a simple example application using QT-QML and JavaScript.
In this i am using HTTP Requests, I have on Button that sends HTTP request using JavaScript.

When I receive response of the HTTP request in the call back function i am trying to read the state of the HTTP response as follows.

```
if( httpReq.readyState == 4 ) //Problem
{   
    if(httpReq.status == 200 )
    {
           ...
```

I am trying to check if `readyState` is `4` (4 represents complete/done)
But if conditions fails to check this and gets evaluated to true regardless of `readyState` value.
For example, if `readyState` is `0` (0 == 4) then also if condition gets evaluated to TRUE which should not.
Why this might be happening.

I have also tried

```
 1. if( parseInt(httpReq.readyState) == 4 ) 
 2. if( Number(httpReq.readyState) == 4 )  
 3. if( httpReq.readyState == '4' )
```

Above conditions also give the same results and gets evaluated to TRUE regardless of `readyState` value.
Is there any problem with my JavaScript Interpreter.

Thanks.

------UPDATE-----

Thing is that, I have QML application (which sends HTTP request) and HTTP server (Which servers this QML HTPP request) both in the same application/process. When I Separate HTTP server and QML application in two different application/executable it does work, and when i combine both the applications in same executable then it creates problem. When i combine both HTTP server and QML application in one executable QML JavaScript interpreter starts behaving weird. I am running QML application in a Separate Thread before running Web server.

Comment: have you tried code like `Number(httpReq.readyState) === 4` ?

Comment: when i write, `logPrint("Result is :"+(httpReq.readyState == 4));` it prints true same with the `===`.

Comment: If you do things in the same process then the problem might come from somewhere else, we really need a minimal code to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
if( httpReq.readyState == 4 ) //Problem
{   
  console.log("Evaluated to true with: " + httpReq.readyState);

...
```

To assert that the condition was truly evaluated to true with a wrong integer?

Alternatively, since you call this in QML, this might come from the way you use javascript with QML, can you show how you invoke the javascript from the QML?

Comment: It is not invoked from the QML, QML have one button -> after clicking button I am calling JS function to send HTTP request using `XMLHttpRequest` object and in the response call back I have this code. I have tried above test and it Prints `Evaluated to true with: 0`

Comment: ok, this will sound really stupid, but are you sure you don't have a ";" just after your if (maybe on the far right, invisible in the editor?)
Can you provide a minimal code?

Answer (score 0):

A minimal example with the described behaviour would be helpful.

The following code works for me without problems:

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Item {
    Component.onCompleted: {
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            console.log("readyState: " + req.readyState);

            if (req.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) { // 4 instead of 'XMLHttpRequest.DONE' works here too
                console.log("Request complete");

                if (req.status == 200) {
                    console.log("Status code: 200");
                    console.log(req.responseText.slice(0, 50) + "...")
                }
            }
        }

        req.open("GET", "http://stackoverflow.com/");
        req.send();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thing is that, i have QML application (which sends HTTP req) and HTTP server (Which servers this QML request) both in the same application/process. When I Separate HTTP server and QML application in two different application/executable it does work, and when i combine both the applications in same executable then it creates problem. When i combine both HTTP server and QML application in one executable QML JavaScript interpreter starts behaving weird. I am running QML application in a Separate Thread before running Web server.